# form object inside of ajaxForm error callback

Tags: jquery, forms, ajaxform

I'm trying to access my form object inside of ajaxForm's error method:

```
$('#foo').ajaxForm({
  error: function(){
    // where's my $('#foo') object?
  }
});
```

error can take 3 params, but none of them are the form object, also this returns the url, but again no form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky, why not use:

```
var myForm = $("#foo");

myForm.ajaxForm({
 error: function(){
  myForm.//whatever
 }
});
```

If there is another way, I'd love to know myself.

Comment: It's nice that success/beforeSubmit all have direct access to the form object and kinda annoying that error isn't consistent with that.

Comment: This works but if you have a page with multiple forms you wouldn't be able to extract the right one, it seems.

Comment: @DavidAndres I have sent a new answer if you love to know it :)

Answer (score 1):

In **ajaxForm** The form element itself is accessible in `beforeSubmit` section:

```
$('#foo').ajaxForm({

   beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm) {
        var myform = jqForm[0];
        /*
         If there are multiple forms in the selector, 
        each form is accessible with its order in the array
        */
   }

  error: function(){
    // where's my $('#foo') object?
    //It is here: myform
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the tab 'Working with Fields' in that plugin's docs, I think you'll find your answer.

For performance, you should probably store a reference to the form before you bind the ajaxForm.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $foo = $('#foo');
    $foo.ajaxForm({
        error: function() {
            alert($('#fieldId', $foo).fieldValue()[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Does `this` not work? I.e.,

```
$('#foo').ajaxForm({
  error: function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
  }
});
```

Comment: @indedmn: Looks like the this keyword in the callback refers to the URL.  See the OP...