# jQuery Ajax form get submitted form as return parameter in case of an error

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to generate and submit my Ajax forms. However if a ajax call fails, I would like to offer the option to option to resend the form and therefore built a displayError() function, which will print an the top bar of the website with the error provided and a button to submit the failed form again.

However, as I am using multiple forms with the same function within this website and with the same class obviously, I need to tell the displayError() function which form was just submitted and failed. Within the beforeSubmit or success function I have a so called "myform" parameter which unfortunately is not available within the error function for whatever reason.

**Is there any possibility to access the current DOM Object of the form submitted within the error function of the ajax call?**

```
$('.class').ajaxForm({ 
    beforeSubmit: function(data, myForm){

    },
    success: function(responseText, status, xhr, myForm){
        displaySuccess(responseText);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        displayError();
    }
});
```

This is just a simplified version of the code I am using but should be enough to understand the problem. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `$(this)` i think

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422143/form-object-inside-of-ajaxform-error-callback apparently there's no form parameter for error and you can't use $(this), but some people have defined variables as a workaround. You might use .each to loop through all forms, and define the form element inside the error handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sh4dowb pointed out running the ajaxform within a .each function is actually the best solution to solve this problem. Just in case someone is experiencing the same issues, I am answering my own question.

```
$('.class').each(function(){
    var that=this;
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function(data, myForm){

        },
        success: function(responseText, status, xhr, myForm){
            displaySuccess(responseText);       
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            displayError(function(){$(that).submit()});
        }
    });
});
```

This actually solved my problem. As just as mentioned above, this is just a simplified version of the complete script again.